# Excel and 64 bits

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2008, ssis, connection-string

I'm doing a SSIS package with some excel connections. This is my enviornment:

- Microsoft office 2007 installed
- Microsoft office 2010 installed
- SQL Server 2008 R2 installed
- Visual Studio 2008 installed
- Visual Studio 2010 installed
- Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable installed

this is my connection string to the excel file:

- Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX.xls;Extended Properties=EXCEL 14.0;HDR=YES";

So, when i try to deploy my SSIS package, the following error appeared:

***An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine". Hresult: 0x8000040005 Description: "Could not find installable ISAM"***

It's weird becouse previously I installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable installed and I have both Microsoft Office versions...

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

there are several google results on this matter, did you try: `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209805`?

also remember that Dtexec (used to run the pacakges) has both a 64-bit and a 32-bit application. If you develop a package in a 32-bit environment and want to run the package in a 64-bit environment, the connection managers need to be 64-bit compliant. Some connection managers such as Excel work in a 32-bit environment only.

Comment: Dtexec solution is not valid to execute a dtsx package 'cos I'm executing inside a Sharepoint, So I have to use app.LoadPackage (...)

Comment: yes, but I believe when you call package.Execute() it calls dtexec to run it